# How to turn off screen using xset?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xorg

Hi i am trying to run this script that turn off the screen when i call the script.

Script code:

```
#!/bin/sh
STATUS=`xset -q | grep "Monitor is" | awk '{print $3}'`
if [ "${STATUS}" = "On" ]
then
xset dpms force off
else
xset dpms force on
fi
exit 0
```

But when i call the script, i am getting this error

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  142 (DPMS)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (DPMSForceLevel)
  Serial number of failed request:  10
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

Comment: This doesn't really look like a programming problem (did you write that script or just grab it from somewhere?) but more like an X server configuration issue. Have you actually *looked* at the `xset q` output to see if DPMS is present?

Comment: Try this first: xset +dpms

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316929/display-is-not-capable-of-dpms-after-gnome-wayland-update

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo usage: $(basename $0) "on|off|status"
  exit 1
fi

if [ $1 = "off" ]; then
  echo -en "Turning monitor off..."
  xset dpms force off
  echo -en "done.\nCheck:"
  xset -q|grep "Monitor is"
elif [ $1 = "on" ]; then
  echo -en "Turning monitor on..."
  xset dpms force on
  echo -en "done.\nCheck:"
  xset -q|grep "Monitor is"
elif [ $1 = "status" ]; then
  xset -q|sed -ne 's/^[ ]*Monitor is //p'
else 
  echo usage: $(basename $0) "on|off|status"
fi
```

From here: http://systembash.com/content/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-via-command-line-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

```
    STATUS_MONITOR=$(xset q | grep "Monitor is" | awk '{print $3}')

    if [ "$STATUS_MONITOR" == "On" ]; then

        echo "Status = "$STATUS_MONITOR

    else

        echo "Status = "$STATUS_MONITOR

    fi
```

Its worked for me.